# javascript error: circular reference error while trying to retrieve navigator.plugins using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, navigator, circular-reference

I'm trying to retrieve the value of `navigator.plugins` from a [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context*.

Using [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) I'm able to retrieve `navigator.userAgent` and `navigator.plugins` as follows:

[image: navigator_userAgent_plugins]

But using *Selenium*'s `execute_script()` method I'm able to extract the `navigator.userAgent` but `navigator.plugins` raises the following *circular reference* error:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver 

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  print("userAgent: "+driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  print("plugins: "+driver.execute_script("return navigator.plugins;"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Debanjan\PyPrograms\navigator_properties.py", line 19, in <module>
      print("vendor: "+driver.execute_script("return navigator.plugins;"))
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
      'args': converted_args})['value']
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
      self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
      raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: circular reference
    (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
  ```

I've been through the following discussions on *circular reference* and I understand the concept. But I am not sure how should I address the issue here.

- [Example of a circular reference in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493453/example-of-a-circular-reference-in-javascript)
- [Detecting and fixing circular references in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962018/detecting-and-fixing-circular-references-in-javascript)
- [Is circular reference between objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334440/is-circular-reference-between-objects-a-bad-practice)

Can someone help me to retrieve the `navigator.plugins` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Circular Reference

A [circular reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/why-circular-reference-is-bad-in-javascript) occurs if two separate objects pass references to each other. Circular referencing implies that the 2 objects referencing each other are tightly coupled and changes to one object may need changes in other as well.

---

### NavigatorPlugins.plugins

[NavigatorPlugins.plugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins/plugins) returns a [PluginArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PluginArray) object, listing the [Plugin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Plugin) objects describing the plugins installed in the application. `plugins` is `PluginArray` object used to access `Plugin` objects either by name or as a list of items. The returned value has the length property and supports accessing individual items using bracket notation (e.g. `plugins[2]`), as well as via `item(index)` and `namedItem("name")` methods.

---

To extract the `navigator.plugins` properties you can use the following solutions:

- To get the list of *names* of the `plugins`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script("return Array.from(navigator.plugins).map(({name}) => name);"))
  ```

  - Console Output:

    ```
    ['Chrome PDF Plugin', 'Chrome PDF Viewer', 'Native Client']
    ```
- To get the list of *filename* of the `plugins`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script("return Array.from(navigator.plugins).map(({filename}) => filename);"))
  ```

  - Console Output:

    ```
    ['internal-pdf-viewer', 'mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai', 'internal-nacl-plugin']
    ```
- To get the list of *description* of the `plugins`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script("return Array.from(navigator.plugins).map(({description}) => description);"))
  ```

  - Console Output:

    ```
    ['Portable Document Format', '', '']
    ```

Answer (score 3):

There might be a serialization issue when you query a non-primitive data structure from a browser realm.
By closely inspecting the hierarchy of a single plugin, we can see it has a recursive structure which is an issue for the serializer.
[image]

If you need a list of plugins, try returning just a serialized, newline-separated string and then split it by a newline symbol in the Python realm.

For example:

```
plugins = driver.execute_script("return Array.from(navigator.plugins).map(({name}) => name).join('\n');").split('\n')
```

Comment: With `print("plugins->name: "+driver.execute_script("return Array.from(navigator.plugins).map(({name}) => name);"))` I'm seeing _TypeError: must be str, not list_

Comment: Ok, then just return it as newline-separated string. For example: return Array.from(navigator.plugins).map(({name}) => name).join('\n'); Then just split it by \n in your Python code to get a list of stirngs.

Comment: With `print("plugins->name: "+driver.execute_script("return Array.from(navigator.plugins).map(({name}) => name);")[0])` I get back _Chrome PDF Plugin_, _Chrome PDF Viewer_ and so on.

Comment: That is not what I suggested above. In your case you just return the name of a first available plugin. What I suggested to do is to return a newline-separated string from your call to execute_script and then slit it by "\n" in your Python code to get a list of stirngs.
For example:
plugins =  driver.execute_script("return Array.from(navigator.plugins).map(({name}) => name).join('\n')").split('\n')
print('plugins->name: ' + plugins)

Comment: @ViacheslavMoskalenko All you need to add is `.join()` to the end and it will return a comma-delimited string of names, `return Array.from(navigator.plugins).map(({name}) => name).join()`

Comment: @JeffC, The separator could be anything. A newline is just an example. If a plugin has "," as part of the name, then we shouldn't be relying on the default separator, which is a comma.

Comment: Understood but you are taking an array of string, joining it, then splitting it. I don't understand the purpose. Your answer is returning an array, which is likely a problem. If you add just `.join()` it will return a string which will be fine.

Comment: I'll adjust my answer because I wasn't aware execute_script can only return a string. If you take a look at my comments above, I've suggested gluing a list of strings (the available plugin names) to be later split in the Python realm. The author needs a list of available plugins which is why we have to split a string returned to us by execute_script.

Comment: @DebanjanB, does that matches result you were initially envisioned?

Comment: @ViacheslavMoskalenko Your initial answer took me to a point where I'm able to dig further. Definitely, that was helpful. I'm still trying to retrieve the _plugin_ values.

Comment: @ViacheslavMoskalenko The previous version of your answer was working. Can you update the line of code as per the previous version please?

Comment: @DebanjanB, could you, please, clarify?
What isn't working at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that [`navigator.plugins`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins/plugins) returns a [PluginArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PluginArray).

The `PluginArray` page lists the methods and properties that are available and with that I wrote this code that returns the list of names. You can adapt it to whatever you need.

```
print("plugins: " + driver.execute_script("var list = [];for(var i = 0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++) { list.push(navigator.plugins[i].name); }; return list.join();"))
```

Comment: Definitely this answer helps to move one step ahead. Somehow, I need to get the _plugin_ values.

Comment: What plugin values are you looking for specfically?

Comment: I was looking to extract the values from 1) Chrome PDF Plugin 2) Chrome PDF Viewer 3) Native Client

Comment: Which values are you looking for? Have you looked at the PluginArray page I linked in my answer? It links to the Plugin page which has the different properties you can access: description, filename, and version. Is that what you're looking for or ?

Comment: So what's the overall goal here? You should probably update your question with that. Are you trying to locate a specific plugin, make sure a specific plugin is not installed, etc.? Once we have that, we can better create an answer.