# Socket.io fetchSockets() error between redis nodes

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-redis

We are having issuses using *server.fetchSockets()* in socket.io redis nodes. When a server call this function the others servers are throwing this exception:

```
C:\path\node_modules\socket.io-redis\dist\index.js:212
                response = JSON.stringify({
                                ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Pool'
    |     property 'config' -> object with constructor 'PoolConfig'
    |     property 'connectionConfig' -> object with constructor `ConnectionConfig'
    --- property 'pool' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at RedisAdapter.onrequest (C:\Users\pach\Documents\trace gaming\new\node\node_modules\socket.io-redis\dist\index.js:212:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
```

and the server that is calling the function gets a timeout.

Sending and receiving events are working fine.

**socket.io 4.1.1
socket.io-redis 6.1.1**

[Function doc link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#server-fetchSockets)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has something to do with the first bit of the TypeError `Converting circular structure to JSON`. I am new to socket.io so this is just my assumption but I think each socket instance has references to itself within its data structure. Therefore when trying to parse to json you end up in a recursive loop that the engine notices and errors out of after a while hence the location the error occurs `processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)`.

If you log a socket instance to the console you can look through it and see that some of the sockets are valued as `circular`. Again this is just my gut feeling on your issue but I am curious to know if you have solved it and what the issue really was!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the object you want to convert is not meant to be converted to a JSON String or in other words: `JSON.stringify` does not know, when it has to stop converting already seen/converted objects.

The [drawing](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#socket) in the beginning of the socket-help explains the structure a bit.

Every client has a reference to the server, the server has references to all clients. So if you call `JSON.stringify()` on any of these objects the error occurs.

This is just a rudimentary example how the references are set to help you understanding the error message:

```js
myServer = { clients: [] };
myClient = { server: myServer };

myServer.clients.push(myClient);
/**
 * If you call now myServer.clients[0].server
 * you have the same reference as if you would call myServer.
 *
 * You could continue this to infinity and beyond
 * with addition calls to .clients[0].server
 *
 * And that's the reason why the error occurs.
 * There is no end-condition.
 */
console.log(
  myServer
    .clients[0].server
    .clients[0].server
    .clients[0].server == myServer);
```

##### How to avoid circular references:

You can add a replacer-function to `JSON.stringify(obj, replacer)`.

```js
const obj = {};
obj.reference = obj;

function jsonWithoutCircular(obj) {
  let list = [], replacer = (name, val) => {
    if (typeof val == "function")
      return;
    if (typeof val == "object") {
      if (!list.includes(val)) {
        if (val) // only if not null
          list.push(val);
        return val;
      } else {
        return "*** CIRCULAR REFERENCE ***";
      }
    } else {
      return val
    }
  };
  return JSON.stringify(obj, replacer)
}

try {
  JSON.stringify(obj);
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}

console.log(jsonWithoutCircular(obj));

try {
  JSON.stringify(globalThis); // or window
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}

// the error that appears here is related to window.parent
console.log(jsonWithoutCircular(window));
```

Other questions that may be useful:

- [How to avoid circular reference in OOP Javascript?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/318661/how-to-avoid-circular-reference-in-oop-javascript)
- [Example of a circular reference in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493453/example-of-a-circular-reference-in-javascript)
- [Is circular reference between objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334440/is-circular-reference-between-objects-a-bad-practice)
- [And a lot more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+circular+reference)